# Как создать динамический массив структур в qt правильно

Tags: qt

Я создаю массив структур через вектор.

```
QVector <Str_Message> S_M;  // задаём вектор в который складываем стуктуру
```

Но  я слышал что это не верный путь. Еще бы хотел узнать как это делать правильно.

**Узнать методы и механизмы принятые в профессиональных сферах**, ибо не давно узнал что в Qt собираются отказаться от QVector ибо он резервирует память в любом месте из-за чего очень сильно падает работа с памятью.

Comment: меня терзают смутные сомнения на счет "резервирует память в любом месте из за чего очень сильно падает работа с памятью", похоже, вы что-то совсем не так поняли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QVector` это правильный способ, не нравится он, используйте `std::vector`.

А по поводу производительности, в проффесиональных сферах принято использовать профилировщики для поиска узких мест, а не статьи из интернета. А то, чем вы озаботились называется преждевременная оптимизация, она враг любого проекта, как говорил великий Дейкстра.